# MVC Datalist is not working on prod server but works on Dev

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, autocomplete, html-datalist

I have an application that uses a datalist that works in the Dev environment but returns a blank field with no lookup in the Production environment. I want to use datalist extensively as it easily provides an auto complete facility but cannot until it works in Production.

Dev is MVC VS 2010 on IE 11.0 under Win7 and it scores 302 in the HTML5Test.
Production is IE 11.0 on Server 2012 R2 Standard reported as Win8.1 and scores 312 in the HTML5Test.

After much comparing, checking, trying, inspecting and reviewing I have found the source of the issue that stops datalist working.

**MVC View Code in Index.cshtml**
This is the eventual experimental code trying to isolate the issue:

```
@model IEnumerable<CRM_MVC.Models.BranchDiary>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<body>
<div>
    <lable>Enter TV Series Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="tv" name="series" list="tvseries" autofocus>
    <datalist id="tvseries">
        <option value="Heroes">
        <option value="Lost">
        <option value="Fringe">
        <option value="CriminalMinds">
        <option value="CSIMiami">
    </datalist>

    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Internet Explorer session showing Index.cshtml
[image: Index Screen Print]

The field should provide an autocomplete dropdown but doesn’t.

[image: Index Inspect showing incorrect datalist]

The Inspect screen shows that `<datalist id=tv>` is wrongly terminated by /datalist on the same line and after the option list /datalist wrongly has //datalist appearing after it.

When right click Edit HTML is selected for the Div, the original HTML correctly has the first datalist tag with no /datalist and the option list is correctly terminated at the end by the /datalist tag.

[image: Inspect showing Edit HTML]

What can be done to stop the extras being added to  so that it might work the same on Production as on Dev?

Comment: Looks like the browser, in this case, IE5 (technically, IE running in IE5 mode), is trying to "correct" the "error" it finds in the source. In the same screenschot, there is also a `<lable></lable>` and a few lines down, `</label><//label>`, which is caused by an actual error! So, what you need to do is try and run this in IE10 mode or higher.

Comment: And run your HTML through the W3C validator to fix things like the `<lable>` mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your considered reply. I appreciate the time and thought you have given to this. I will try what you have suggested. I have spent many hours working on this issue with no success over the last 3 days. It was only on Saturday afternoon that I found it was 'adjusting' the html by itself. Using the W3C validator is a good idea and I will run the actual code through it as well as this test snippet. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as turning off compatibility mode on the production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved this was unchecking **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** in IE Tools-> Compatibility View Settings.
Thanks to Mr Lister for this suggestion.
[image: IE 11 Compatibility View Settings]

I will need to check to see if globally changing this setting affects anything else but it makes autocomplete work now as expected and required. Thanks again to Mr Lister for the assistance.

[image: Sample autocomplete working now]